# R to Oracle Connection

Tags: r, oracle, dbconnection

I am trying to connect R with Oracle using RJDBC. I am using the following code -

```
library(RJDBC)

jdbcDriver = JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",classpath="~/lib/ojdbc14.jar") 

jdbcConnection = dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:port/SID,username, password)
```

And I am getting error in third line -

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1], :java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor. The connection descriptor used by client was: 
>   //hostname:port/SID,username, password

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?
Also is there any other way to connect R with Oracle? Thanks.

Comment: do you have the variables `username` and `password` stored in your environment?

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe Yes that is correct, it contains username and password.

Comment: so do you not need to paste the strings together? i.e `jdbcConnection = dbConnect(jdbcDriver, paste0("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:port/SID",username, password))`

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe I am still getting same error.

Comment: I have also tried using the actual username and password in quotes. But still I am getting same error.